# zero a esquerda do número (tipo number)

Tags: javascript

```
<input oninput="if (this.value.length > this.maxLength)
 this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);
 validity.valid||(value='');" min="0" step="1" type="number"
 maxlength="9" formControlName="quantity" class="form-control"
 [ngClass]="item.controls['quantity'].errors ? 'has-error' : ''"
 (keydown)="onValueOrQuantityChanged(item)"
 (keyup)="onValueOrQuantityChanged(item)">
```

Eu tenho o código html acima que insere um input do tipo NUMBER. Junto tem um código javascript que asssegure que eu não digite mais de 9 números.

O problema é que quando minha aplicação roda no Firefox, ao digitar zero(s) a esquerda, é (são) descartado(s) depois de digitar os 9 números.

Ex. ao digitar "000999999", os zeros são descartados e o posso digitar mais 3 números no final do valor. Mas eu quero manter esses zeros.

OBS.: está acontecendo apenas no Firefox.

Comment: ele não apresenta nenhum erro no console?

Comment: Se não for causar nenhum problema, mude para `type='text'` e veja se resolve.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo estamos usando como requisito que o campo não pode aceitar caractere outro que número (requisito pedido pelo cliente)

Comment: @AlvaroAlves nenhuma mensagem de erro

Comment: @Cris.tal neste caso, coloque uma máscara no campo, ou utilize um `input.replace(/\D/g, '')` num evento `keyup`.

Comment: Se vc quer manter os zeros, pq está usando slice?